# Interpolation of values on random points in 2D

Tags: algorithm, interpolation

Let me start with an example. In OpenGL when you draw a triangle with different colors on each vertex, values of color on points in between is interpolated:

[image: Triangle]

Now, lets say I have collection of random points, which can be represented like that (black is counted as a lack of color):

[image: Points]

How can I efficiently interpolate those points so I will get evenly filled picture?

Comment: Delaunay triangulation followed by some barycentric interpolation.  Care needed at boundary of space.

Comment: Is there no image processing based approach (image as an input, not collection of points)?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark What do you mean by "care needed at boundary of space". I mean I know why, but what approach do you suggest?

Comment: @mrpyo: That depends on what you want to achieve. For example, should the top left pixel be black, because it lies outside the point cloud? Or should it be bright purple, because the purple spot is close? If you use the [Bowyer-Watson algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowyer%E2%80%93Watson_algorithm), you will start with a huge triangle that surrounds your image. You could make this triangle's vertices black. If it is big enough, the border should have a colour similar to the closest point. You could also mirror points close to the edges along these edges to get a uniform ditribution.

Comment: Did you solve this? I want to do this too.

Comment: Did someone solve this ? I'm lost at the part of applying barycentric interpolation into triangles.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to to encode your colors with a value and then do a surface fitting c=f(x,y) from (xi, yi, ci) where xi and yi are the (x,y) coordinates of point i and ci is the encoded color value at point i. You don't need to do extra handle at boundary space as evaluating the color value at a boundary point is the same as evaluating the color at any point.

Answer (score 2):

1. Divide area into triangles. Choose your method from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_set_triangulation.
2. For each triangle perform interpolation as normally for single triangle

Answer (score 1):

This solution from another stackoverflow question helped me:
https://jsfiddle.net/87nw05kz/

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("testcanvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const colors = [{x:10,y:10,r:255,g:0,b:0},
                            {x:190,y:10,r:0,g:127,b:0},
                            {x:100,y:190,r:0,g:0,b:255},
                            {x:200,y:100,r:0,g:0,b:0},
                            {x:190,y:190,r:127,g:255,b:127}];

function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        let dx = x1 - x2;
    let dy = y1 - y2;
    return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
function calculateColor(x, y) {
        let total = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            let c = colors[i];
        let d = distance(c.x, c.y, x, y);
        if (d === 0) {
                return c;
        }
        d = 1 / (d * d);
        c.d = d;
        total += d;
        }
    let r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            let c = colors[i];
            let ratio = c.d / total;
        r += ratio * c.r;
        g += ratio * c.g;
        b += ratio * c.b;
    }
    r = Math.floor(r);
    g = Math.floor(g);
    b = Math.floor(b);
    return {r:r,g:g,b:b};
}
              
function processImage() {
    const imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    const pixels = imgData.data;
    const width = canvas.width;
    const height = canvas.height;
    const count = width * height * 4;
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i += 4) {
            let x = (i / 4) % width;
        let y = Math.floor(i / 4 / width);
        let color = calculateColor(x, y);
        pixels[i] = color.r;
        pixels[i+1] = color.g;
        pixels[i+2] = color.b;
        pixels[i+3] = 255;
        
    }
    context.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}

processImage();
```