# How to color the whole image when only colors of few certain coordinates are given

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have markers on an object and gave certain colors to them individually(using some function) now I have to color the whole object by selecting each and every pixel of the object and interpolating it to the nearest four markers.This process is taking a lot of time. I want to know if there is any other way to color. i just want to colour the object in a way so that it depends on the color of the markers[image: the white things are the markers][image: the image i get after interpolating the markers colors]In the first image the markers are all white but when i perform the operation they are given different colors

I want to know if there is a way to imagine colors between the markers

Comment: See grid mesh interpolation https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.PiecewiseAffineTransform

Comment: You could also implement a Shepards (inverse square warp), but it would be very slow. Alternately, divide the grid into rectangles and divide each into two triangles, then do barycentric interpolation of the 3 corner colors. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61854897/how-to-apply-a-three-point-triangle-gradient-in-opencv/61862324#61862324